# Mudar o nome do index.php com .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess

Galera, eu queria acessar o index.php a partir de qualquer parametro na url, a partir do .htaccess, assim:

```
site.com/sistema1
site.com/sistema2
...
```

e ir automaticamente para

```
site.com/index.php
```

pra depois eu tratar determinadas funções a partir dessa url. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php`

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar aqui.. já estava cogitando criar várias pastas iguais